# If $A + B + C = \pi$, then show that $\sin(A) + \sin(B) + \sin(C) = 4\cos\frac{A}{2}\cos\frac{B}{2}\cos\frac{C}{2}$

Tags: trigonometry

So i have 
$A + B + C = \pi$

$$\frac{A}{2} + \frac {B}{2} + \frac{C}{2} = \frac{\pi}{2}$$

$$4\cos\left(\frac{-B-C + \pi}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{-A -C + \pi}{2}\right)\cdots$$
 And I doubt this leads to anywhere.

So then I tried, 
$\sin\left(\frac{-B-C + \pi}{2}\right)\cdots$ and this didn't go anywhere either. 
I don't know what to try, and I've seen other people's solutions and they do something like:
$\sin(C) = \sin(A + B)$, $\cos(C/2) = \sin(\frac{A + B}{2})$ but i don't see where they got this part from. Other people use Euler's formula or whatever but I haven't learned that yet so I can't use it.

Comment: +1.  But on the other hand, I know I've answered this one here before.  There's an argument from old-fashioned trigonometric identities, but I posted an argument showing that either the right side or the left can be viewed as the area of a certain triangle; hence they must be equal.

Comment: @MichaelHardy: Oh, sorry, I did google the problem but I did not find any similar problems on math.stackexchange.

Comment: Maybe I haven't answered EXACTLY this one.....

Comment: ....and maybe this version isn't quite right.....

Comment: Duplicate: [Proving $\sin A + \sin B + \sin C = 4 \cos\frac{A}{2}\cos\frac{B}{2}\cos\frac{C}{2}$]( http://math.stackexchange.com/q/180860/409).

Comment: In the second post, second-third line of @Blue's link, I don't get how he combined the two?

Comment: If you need clarification of an answer on a different page, then you should ask for it in a comment below that answer.

Comment: I've deleted my answer to this version.  I had some bad typos, e.g. $\sin A$ and $\sin\dfrac A2$ were confused with each other.  See the linked earlier question.

Comment: @Kat : You might post separately your other question in a comment under my now-deleted answer.  If $A$ is one angle of a triangle inscribed in a circle of unit DIAMETER, then when is $\sin A$ the length of the side opposite the angle $A$?  Essentially this is a version of the law of sines.  Sometimes that is stated by saying $\dfrac{a}{\sin A}=\dfrac{b}{\sin B}=\dfrac{c}{\sin C}$, where (capital) $A,B,C$ are the angles and (lower-case) $a,b,c$ are the sides.  That version stops short of explicitly saying that that number is the diameter of the circumscribed circle.

Comment: I've up-voted the question and also voted to close it as a duplicated.

Answer (score 1):

$$\sin(A) + \sin(B) + \sin(C)= 2\sin\left(\frac{A+B}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{A - B}{2}\right) + 2\sin\left(\frac{C}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{C}{2}\right) $$

$$\sin(A) + \sin(B) + \sin(C)= 2\cos\left(\frac{C}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{A - B}{2}\right) + 2\sin\left(\frac{C}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{C}{2}\right)$$

$$\sin(A) + \sin(B) + \sin(C)= 2\cos\left(\frac{C}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{A - B}{2}\right) + \cos\left(\frac{A + B}{2}\right)$$

$$\sin(A) + \sin(B) + \sin(C)= 4\cos\left(\frac{A}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{B}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{C}{2}\right)$$