# Prove that $ 1+ \cos A + \cos B + \cos C = 0$.

Tags: trigonometry, proof-writing

If $A+B+C=180^\circ$   and

$\tan \left[\dfrac{A+B-C} 4 \right] \tan \left[ \dfrac{-A+B+C} 4\right]  \tan\left[\dfrac{A-B+C} 4 \right] =1$

then prove that

$ 1+ \cos A + \cos B + \cos C = 0$

I tried to use the formula of $\tan(A+B+C)$, but couldn't solve it.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/624189/prove-that-1-cos-alpha-cos-beta-cos-gamma-0