# tough algebric problem?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I wanted to know how can i prove that if

> $xy+yz+zx=1$, then
>
> $$ \frac{x}{1+x^2}+\frac{y}{1+y^2}+\frac{z}{1+z^2}
>      = \frac{2}{\sqrt{(1+x^2)(1+y^2)(1+z^2)}}$$
>
> I did let $x=\tan A$,  $y=\tan B$,   $z=\tan C$

given $xy+yz+zx =1$ we have $\tan A \tan B+ \tan B \tan C+\tan C \tan A=1$

$\tan C(\tan A+\tan B)=1-\tan A \tan B$, or $\tan(A+B)=\tan(\pi/2 -C)$ we have $A+B+C=\pi/2$.

what to do now?

Any help appreciated.

thanks.

Comment: So your question is whether this problem is tough? Because your title indicates exactly that (it also indicates, by duplication of the question mark, that you don't really believe it).

Comment: @celtschk: Maybe the question is whether it is algebric.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

HINT:

$$\frac x{1+x^2}=\frac {\tan A}{1+\tan^2A}=\frac{2\sin A\cos A}2=\frac{\sin2A}2$$

Now , $$\sin2A+\sin2B+\sin2C=2\sin(A+B)\cos(A-B)+2\sin C\cos C$$

$$=2\sin\left(\frac\pi2-C\right)\cos(A-B)+2\sin C\cos C$$

$$=2\cos C\{\cos(A-B)+\cos(A+B)\}$$ as $\sin C=\sin\{\frac\pi2-(A+B)\}=\cos(A+B)$

$$\implies \sin2A+\sin2B+\sin2C=2\cos C\cdot2\cos A\cos B$$

and  $$\frac1{\sqrt{1+x^2}}=\frac1{\sec A}=\cos A$$

Comment: do you people even blink, before answering o_o.

Comment: @Shobhit, not sure if I clearly understood your statement. But have you noticed $\tan(A+B)=\tan\left(\frac\pi2-C\right)\implies A+B=n\pi+\frac\pi2-C$ where $n$ is any integer. The above proof hold if $n=2m$(even). What about $n=2m+1$(odd)?

Comment: @Shobhit: This is a really cool problem. May I know the name of the book you are studying from?

Comment: @Shobhit, if $n=2m+1,$ $$\tan\left(A+B\right)=\tan\{(2m+1)\pi+\frac\pi2-C\}=\tan\left(\frac\pi2-C\right)=\cot C,$$ but $$\sin\left(A+B\right)=\sin\{(2m+1)\pi+\frac\pi2-C\}=-\sin\left(\frac\pi2-C\right)=-\cos C$$ and  $$\cos\left(A+B\right)=\cos\{(2m+1)\pi+\frac\pi2-C\}=-\cos\left(\frac\pi2-C\right)=-\sin C$$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee the maths written is not clear mind to take a look.

Comment: @Shobhit, not sure why the comment formatting got corrupted. My point is if $n=2m+1,\sin(A+B)=-\cos C$ and $\sin C=-\cos(A+B)$ I am trying to figure out what happens if we consider the general value of $A+B+C$ which is $n\pi+\frac\pi2$

Comment: @Shobhit, btw another similar problem is $$\sum \frac x{1-x^2}=4\prod \frac x{1-x^2}$$ if $xy+yz+zx=1$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee its the same, let $x=tanA, y=tanB, z=tanC$ ,multiply and divide L.H.S by 2 to get L.H.S =$\frac12(tan2A+tan2B+tan2C)$, also solving $xy+yz+zx =1$, we get $A+B+C=\frac\pi{2}$ , applying $tan(2A+2B)=tan(\pi-2C)$ or $tan2A+tan2B+tan2C=tan2A*tan2B*tan2C$, which is R.H.S on simplifying.Good question.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer by `lab bhattacharjee' is perfectly fine. For what it's worth, there's a nice geometric view that might enrich this nearly-4-year-old post a tiny bit.

The identity to be proven is, given $\alpha + \beta + \gamma = \frac{\pi}2$, $$ \frac12 \big( \sin 2\alpha + \sin 2\beta + \sin 2\gamma \big) = 2 \cos\alpha \cdot \cos\beta  \cdot\cos\gamma$$

Consider an **acute** triangle $\triangle MNP$ as shown in the figure, with its circumcenter denoted as point $O$. Without loss of generality, take the circumcircle as the unit circle. That is,
$$\text{diameter}~~ \overline{PP'} = 2 \qquad \text{radius}~~ \overline{OM} = \overline{ON} = \overline{OP} = 1$$

By definition, all angles are acute so that any one of them can be split into two parts, say, $\angle PMN = \alpha + \beta < \frac{\pi}2$, with a remaining complement $\gamma > 0$, as in $$\alpha + \beta + \gamma = \frac{\pi}2$$

[image]

The desired identity comes from calculating the area $\mathcal{A} \equiv |\triangle MNP|$ in two different ways:

$$\begin{align}
&\text{RHS}: & \mathcal{A} &= \frac12 \cdot \overline{MP} \cdot \overline{MN} \cdot \sin(\angle PMN ) \\
&\text{LHS}: & \mathcal{A} &= |\triangle OMP| + |\triangle ONM| +|\triangle OPN|
\end{align}$$

For the RHS, we have $$\overline{MP} = 2\cos\alpha \qquad \overline{MN} = 2\cos\beta$$ since point $O$ is the circumcenter (e.g. $\overline{MO} = 1$ and $\triangle MOP$ is an isosceles, $\overline{MP}$ is bisected by the height to point $O$). That is, 
$$\begin{align}
&\text{RHS}: & \mathcal{A} &= \frac12 \cdot \overline{MP} \cdot \overline{MN} \cdot \sin(\angle PMN ) \\
&&  &= \frac12 \cdot 2\cos\alpha \cdot 2\cos\beta \cdot \sin(\alpha + \beta) \\
&& &= 2\cos\alpha \cdot \cos\beta \cdot \sin(\frac{\pi}2 - \gamma) \\
&& &= 2\cos\alpha \cdot \cos\beta \cdot\cos\gamma
\end{align}$$

Now, for the LHS we again apply the Law of Sines to each of the small triangles. For example,
$$\begin{align}
\triangle{NOP} &= \frac12 \cdot \overline{ON} \cdot \overline{OP} \cdot \sin(\angle NOP) \\
&= \frac12 \cdot 1 \cdot 1 \cdot \sin(\pi - \angle NOP') \\
&= \frac12 \sin(\pi - 2\gamma) 
\end{align}$$
since $\angle NOP'$ is the central angle for the inscribed angle $\gamma$ (and $\triangle PMN$ is acute so $O$ is "inside"). Therefore, we have
$$\triangle{NOP} = \frac12 \sin 2\gamma \qquad \text{and similarly} \qquad \triangle{POM} = \frac12 \sin 2\alpha \quad \triangle{MON} = \frac12 \sin 2\beta$$
which sum to the LHS of the desired identity. Note how this proof (splitting a triangle into 3 inner ones) naturally exhibits the cyclic nature (3-fold symmetry) of the identity. $~~~~~$***Q.E.D.***

When the triangle is obtuse, the proof is similar: one of $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ is negative, which corresponding 'inner' triangle becomes `outer', and its effective area is also negative). For the case where two of $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ are negative, unfortunately the notion of a triangle breaks down (unless one considers projective geometry, I guess).

P.S.

I definitely have seen this triangle-splitting analysis before at various places, with respect to any general point and not just the circumcenter. The corresponding algebraic expression involves more than 3 angles.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Nice approach.+1

Comment: Just noticed that I reinvented the wheels (as most efforts by most people are): [this by Blue](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/180906/356647), and this [earlier  by Michael Hardy](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/177259/356647), while he himself probably didn't remember he did essentially [the same thing already earlier](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/154538/356647).