# Formula for summing an arbitrary number $n$ of cos functions?

Tags: trigonometry, summation, trigonometric-series

[This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/176892/prove-trigonometry-identity-for-cos-a-cos-b-cos-c) gives

$$\cos A+\cos B+\cos C=1+4\sin \frac {A}{2}\sin \frac {B}{2}\sin \frac {C}{2}$$

Is it possible to derive a generalised formula for

$$\cos A+\cos B+\cos C+...+\cos N$$

i.e., a formula for summing an arbitrary number $n$ of $\cos$ functions? Perhaps something along the lines of

$$\cos A+\cos B+\cos C+...+\cos N=1+(n+1)\sin \frac {A}{2}\sin \frac {B}{2}\sin \frac {C}{2}...\sin \frac {N}{2}$$

But that's just a wild guess, and I'd have no idea how to prove it.

Comment: You fail to mention that that formula is predicated on $A+B+C=\pi$.

Comment: Is your question also conditioned to $A+B+ \cdots + N = \pi$ ?

Comment: OK, to clarify, I'm looking for a formula for $\cos A \pi x+...+\cos N \pi x$

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem true in general, let try with some numerical value to disprove that.

For this special case we can refer to [Lagrange's trigonometric identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Lagrange's_trigonometric_identities)

$$\sum_{n=1}^N \cos (n\theta)  = -\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sin\left(\left(N+\frac{1}{2}\right)\theta\right)}{2\sin\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)}$$

Comment: I can see that this disproves my suggested general solution - but I can't see how it helps me arrive at a *correct* general solution for $\cos A\pi x+\cos B\pi x+...+\cos N\pi x$, because the Lagrange identity only works for $n={1,2,3...N}$, not for arbitrary values of ${A,B,C...N}$.